# how to get use identity column value before transaction done?

Tags: sql, t-sql, transactions, sql-server-2008-r2

Suppose I have 3 tables in my database like this:

- `Person` (`personid`, ...)  ---this is entity, `personid` is identity column
- `Phone` (`phoneid`, ...)    ---this is entity, `phoneid` is identity column
- `PersonPhone` (`personid, phoneid`)   ---this relationship

When I insert data into tables, I need to insert rows into the entity tables first and get the generated `id`, and then I need to insert a row into the relationship table.

It's working fine. Question is: I have a stored procedure with transaction with `Try Catch` statement like:

```
BEGIN TRY
declare aCursor cursor local fast_forward for (Select Query...)

open aCursor;
fetch next from aCursor into @variables....

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin

   INSERT INTO Person(...);
   set @personid =@@IDENTITY;

   INSERT INTO Phone(...);
   set @phoneid =@@IDENTITY;

   INSERT INTO PersonPhone(@personid, @phoneid);       
end; 

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    close aCursor;
    deallocate selectdistributor;
     SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;    
    ROLLBACK TRAN;
    RETURN;
END CATCH  
COMMIT;  
close aCursor;
deallocate aCursor;
```

With the cursor, there is more the one records will be inserted for person, phone. When run the SP, it will stop for first time data insert on relationship. Also I can get right @personid, @phoneid, but before the transaction is done, I get error on INSERT INTO PersonPhone(@personid, @phoneid); as:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "Person_PersonPhone_FK1". The conflict occurred in database "MYDB", table "dbo.Person", column 'PersonID'.

Looks like Id generated by system not recognized before transaction done.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`? You really should forget that `@@IDENTITY` exists. It is quite possible you have a trigger on either Person or Phone and you are not getting the ID value that you think you're getting.

Comment: Also, can you explain how your SELECT query identifies that a particular person belongs with a particular phone? (I think there is a much more efficient way to do this without all the cursor mumbo-jumbo.) What is the purpose of the 3rd table for what seems like a simpler relationship than that (is Person <-> Phone really many-to-many?).

Comment: Thank you very much. I do have trigger on the table. After change @@Identity to Scope_Identity(), there is no error any more, but no any record inserted!

Comment: Thank you very much. Figured it out and resolve this problem. should use Scope_Identity() instead of @@IDENTITY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely your problem is that you used @@identity which should underr no circumstances ever be used for this purpose. If one of the tables has a trigger, it is possoble to return the wrong value (the identity from the table the trigger is inserting into) and that value coincidentally does not exist in the table that the foreign key links to.

So suppose you havea trigger onteh first table that iunserts to an audit table with an identity. The record is inserted with an ID of 1234. BUt the tirigger inserts to a differnt table and so value retiurned by @@Identity is 5678 which does not exist inteh orginal table. When you go to insert to the table with the FK back on the first table, you get theerror message because  value 5678 does not exist in the first table.

Use the OUTPUT clause instead. You could also use scope_identity(), but output is more flexible (And lets you do multiple record inserts and receive all the identities back as well as the other fields which might uniquely identify a record.

And I'm with Aaron, I would not use a cursor for this unless someone threatened my life.